# Any tricks to adjust windows that are not collinear?

Tags: framing, windows, trim, window-frame

I spent so much time making sure each window was level and plumb that I didn't think to make sure they were equal to each other. Now that they're flashed and nailed, they're about 3/8" off which I can tell when I look at it (not sure anyone can).

My plan is to vinyl side this shop and I'm worried the issue will be exacerbated once the siding goes on. I'm hoping I can tweak the windows so it's not noticeable without having to remove them and start over.

My initial thought was to add 3" trim around the windows and to cut the left one a little larger on the top and a smaller larger on the bottom to level it out. Would this work?

[image]

Comment: Trick 1: live with it. Trick 2: rip out and redo. Trick 1 tends to be the winner unless you are contractor working for someone else and ignored the plans.

Comment: You won't notice it. The only reasons you do now are 1) it's fresh in your mind, and 2) there's a seam in the Tyvek right there. Unless you have a siding edge _right there_ it'll fade from memory before long. Almost no one else will ever see it.

Comment: Ecnerwal & isherwood are correct. However, your idea of adjusting with the trim is a good one. But I think I would only do it if the trim is going to be a different color than the siding. That would make it a little more noticeable.

Comment: You could fiddle the trim (personally, I wouldn't), but if you don't, try to make sure the bottom/top of the windows is around the middle of the siding. (In other words, don't have a siding seam too close to the bottom/top planes.)

Comment: @isherwood every time the OP looks at it they will notice it, especially when the siding goes on and the window height to the next line of siding is different on each window.

Comment: Once nice, even horizontal lines have been drawn across the face of the wall with siding, it will be even more noticeable. Ignoring it will only drive the OP mad. Please do stop back by to tell us what you did!

Answer (score -1):

You could grow vines on it. It's also excellent to keep it cool in summer.

[image]

Comment: On vinyl siding? Erm....

Comment: On _any_ building? Not good for the building...

Comment: You have to trim it at the top so it doesn't cause leaks in the roof.